How does type narrowing work in typescript in switch statement for types whose values are "connected" via generic argument
I have an example like this
enum EnumType {
  Type1 = "Type 1",
  Type2 = "Type 2",
  Type3 = "Type 3",
}

export type MapType = {
  [EnumType.Type1]: string[];
  [EnumType.Type2]: number[];
  [EnumType.Type3]: boolean[];
};

interface MyType<Type extends keyof MapType> {
  id: string;
  type: Type;
  value: MapType[Type];
}

const narrowByType = (obj: MyType<keyof MapType>) => {
  switch (obj.type) {
    case EnumType.Type1:
      const value = obj.value;
  }
};


I was expecting type of value to be string[] since to my knowledge I narrowed the type down, since mapped value for value property and type property are connected.
Expected type was: const value: string[].
Resulted type was: const value: number[] | string[] | boolean[].
Is this possible to achieve in Typescript without doing assertion with as keyword?

The type MyType<keyof MapType> isn't what you want it to be; that just makes type equal to EnumType and value equal to string[] | number[] | boolean[]. The connection in your mind is not represented by that type. You'd need to distribute MyType<K> across unions in K. There are multiple ways to do this. See this playground link for demonstrations. Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what's missing?

@jcalz this is exactly what I wanted! Works perfectly. Can you explain this in a bit detail when you get the chance? I would really like to dive into this more and to see what I did wrong and how does this fix issue. thanks!

I will post an answer when I get a chance, but... MyType<keyof MapType> is a single object type and doesn't "connect" the properties. If you had a type like {x: string | number, y: string | number}, that's not the same as {x: string, y: string} | {x: number, y: number}.

The type MyType<keyof MapType> isn't what you want to be using here. If we examine it:
type Z = MyType<keyof MapType>
/* type Z = {
  id: string;
  type: keyof MapType;
  value: string[] | number[] | boolean[];
} */

we can see that there is no correlation whatsoever between the type of type and the type of value. The type property can be any EnumType, and value can independently be any string[] or number[] or boolean[]:
const z: Z = { id: "", type: EnumType.Type1, value: [false] } // okay

So TypeScript isn't narrowing because there's no reason to narrow.

The type you really want to use is a discriminated union where each member of the union has a type property for just one EnumType member, and whose value property is the one corresponding to that type.  So it should look like:
type Z = {
    id: string;
    type: EnumType.Type1;
    value: string[];
} | {
    id: string;
    type: EnumType.Type2;
    value: number[];
} | {
    id: string;
    type: EnumType.Type3;
    value: boolean[];
}

Now this is an error:
const z: Z = { id: "", type: EnumType.Type1, value: [false] } // error

And now narrowByType works as expected:
const narrowByType = (obj: Z) => {
    switch (obj.type) {
        case EnumType.Type1:
            const value = obj.value;
        //        ^? const value: string[]
    }
};


So now the question is just: how do you write MyType so that MyType<keyof MyType> actually evaluates to the discriminated union above? You need to make sure that MyType<K> distributes over unions in K, so that MyType<K1 | K2 | K3> is equivalent to MyType<K1> | MyType<K2> | MyType<K3>. There are different ways to do this.
The one I usually prefer is to write a distributive object type as coined in microsoft/TypeScript#47109. If you write a mapped type and immediately index into it with the full union of keys, then you end up distributing the mapped property type over the union of keys.  So if you want to distribute F<K> over unions in K, you can write type G<K> = {[P in K]: F<P>}[K].
That gives us:
type MyType<K extends keyof MapType> = { [P in K]: {
    id: string;
    type: P;
    value: MapType[P];
} }[K]

and you can verify that MyType<keyof MapType> evaluates to the desired discriminated union.  In cases like this it's also helpful to give a default type argument:
type MyType<K extends keyof MapType = keyof MapType> = { [P in K]: {
    id: string;
    type: P;
    value: MapType[P];
} }[K]

so now the type MyType without a type argument is also equivalent to the desired discriminated union. If you need just one member of that union you can write MyType<EnumType.Type1>, for example, but if you need the full union, MyType will suffice:
const narrowByType = (obj: MyType) => {
    switch (obj.type) {
        case EnumType.Type1:
            const value = obj.value;
        //        ^? const value: string[]
    }
};

Playground link to code

thank you again for the detail answer. I hope this helps someone as well!

additional question came to mind. would you be able to determine generic type of EnumType passed for a class, based on parameter value property that is of MyType type? here is the playground with this, it just came to my mind that this basically represents inferring type for a class based on property. –
Playground Link

This isn't a good place to discuss additional questions.
